# how get all duplicated genserver calls in one module Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have created 2 genservers.

`camera.ex`

```
defmodule Camera do
  use GenServer

  defmodule Attributes do
    defstruct ~w|name url password port username id owner_id status|a
  end

  def start_link(state \\ %Attributes{} ) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %Attributes{state | id: make_ref()})
  end

  def init(state) do
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def details(pid) do
    GenServer.call(pid, :get)
  end

  def update(pid, map) do
    GenServer.cast(pid, {:update, map})
  end

  def handle_call(:get, _from, state) do
    {:reply, state, state}
  end

  def handle_cast({:update, map}, state) do
    {:noreply, Map.merge(map, state)}
  end
end
```

I have the same Genserver as `user.ex` the only difference between both 2 are the Attributes.

in camera its

```
  defmodule Attributes do
    defstruct ~w|name url password port username id owner_id status|a
  end
```

and in user its

```
  defmodule Attributes do
    defstruct ~w|id username|a
  end
```

and all other calls are duplicated, where I am saving a user/camera or updating a user or camera.

how I can make generic module which I can use in User and Camera, and it will adopt the behaviour of that module and It will help to reduce the duplication. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different approaches: one is to use [`defdelegate/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#defdelegate/2) instead of code duplication.

---

Another one would be to use metaprogramming.

```rb
defmodule Scaffold do
  @moduledoc false

  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote generated: true, location: :keep do
      use GenServer

      defmodule Attributes, do: defstruct unquote(opts)

      def start_link(state \\ %Attributes{}) do
        GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__,
          %Attributes{state | id: make_ref()})
      end

      def init(state), do: {:ok, state}

      def details(pid),
        do: GenServer.call(pid, :get)

      def update(pid, map),
        do: GenServer.cast(pid, {:update, map})

      def handle_call(:get, _from, state),
        do: {:reply, state, state}

      def handle_cast({:update, map}, state),
        do: {:noreply, Map.merge(map, state)}
    end
  end
end
```

and use it as

```rb
defmodule Camera do
  use Scaffold, [:name, :url, ...]
end
```

Comment: what if, there is not `defmodule Attributes, do: defstruct unquote(opts)` and I want to have a state as a list?

Comment: Do whatever you want there, the code will be injected as is.

Comment: great but there will be no opts then, I was concerned about ops, where that will go.

Comment: Don’t use them at all, there is no obligation to use them. Do `use Scaffold`  without argument and declare a default parameter in `__using__/1` callback: `defmacro __using__(opts \\ [])`.